# Using "was" or "had been"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

This is the sentence:

> I went to see it because I **was**/**had been** told it was a good film by all my friends.

I chose `was`, but the correct answer is `had been`. Can someone explain why is it so?

Comment: Either is perfectly fine. Without more information, there is no reason to know why one would be marked as correct over the other.

Comment: That's a tough one

Comment: @JasonBassford, They both are fine indeed, but I think the exercise is intended to be a quizz on using the past perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **went** to see it because I **had been told** it was a good film by all my friends.

You have two separate events here:

The first event:

- Your friends told you the film is good.

The second event (which is, in fact, the **next** event):

- You went to see the film due to your friends' recommendation.

Your sentence indicates that the second event happened **before** the other one as **after** your friends told you about the film, you went to see it (as a result).

Therefore, and since the two events occurred at some time in the past, what happened **first in the past** takes the *past perfect* (in the passive voice because of your sentence structure), and the event that happened **later in the past** takes the *past simple*.